# How to ignore missing library stubs for mypy by adding to pyproject.toml

Tags: python, mypy

I have some libraries which are returning the following error having run `mypy .`

```
module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker
```

To ignore this (as I would like to ignore errors for this particular library) I have tried adding the following to pyproject.toml:

```
+[mypy-<library name>.*]
+ignore_missing_imports = true
```

This however returns the following error:

```
Invalid TOML file /home/...: Empty table name at line ...
```

I was under the impression that this was the correct approach - perhaps things have changed though.

My question is - how do I tell mypy to ignore a particular library missing stubs, and do so within `pyproject.toml`

## Edit

I just found : [mypy overrides in toml are ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159669/mypy-overrides-in-toml-are-ignored)

which suggests something similar to:

```
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = "library.*"
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

Which isn't the syntax I remember, so will leave this up to double check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mypy overrides in toml are ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159669/mypy-overrides-in-toml-are-ignored)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else looking for the answer to this, in addition to that syntax, you can do this as well:

```ini
[tool.mypy-<library name>]
ignore_missing_imports = true
```

Comment: Please note this is the syntax for the `mypy.ini` file not the `pyproject.toml` See [mypy configuration file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#the-mypy-configuration-file)

Comment: This is **not** syntax for `mypy.ini`, you don't need "tool." part for `mypy.ini`. Actually, that looks like syntax for `pyproject.toml`. Config examples: [mypy.ini](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#example-mypy-ini) and [pyproject.toml](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#example-mypy-ini)

Comment: You can do that, but you can't use the asterisk, which means you need these for every module in a package.  But the point of importing from a package namespace is to not care where every type is defined.

Comment: Just leave out the `-<library name>` if there are too many in your project. If there aren't, `# type: ignore[import-untyped]` could suffice.